# How to create a UIButton for tvOS with a clear background color?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to create a UIButton of System type with a clear background color. The problem is that it shows a gray background color even if I set it to clearColor. I can do it with a Custom type UIButton, but then the button loses the default effects for focusing and selection.

[image: Appearance of the System UIButton with a clear background color]

Does anyone knows how to create a System UIButton with a entirely transparent background?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: I didn't, ended up having to create a custom UIButton and implemented the highlight effect myself.

Comment: It would helpful to others if you shared the code of the subclass of UIButton that you ended up using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since tvOS 11 there is a solution for that using the button type "plain" instead of "system" without loosing the effects for focusing and selection:

1. Open the button properties in the Interface builder an select "Type"->"Plain"[image: Button Properties]
2. Set the button background color to "clear color"

Thats it.

Watch Apples Video about "UIButtonTypePlain" here (starts at 13:44):
[UIButtonTypePlain explained](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/?time=1080)

Comment: this destroys the TVOS scroll speed for horizontal items in HStack / LazyHGrid

Answer (score -3):

In storyboard Attributes Inspector you have to change button type *System* to *Custom*.

Comment: he specifically states that he wants a System UIButton.